# Не выполняется cron задача

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, cron, pm2

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, почему не выполняется крон задача?

`@hourly /utils/restart_all_nodejs.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`

В restart_all_nodejs.sh находится одна строчка кода:

`pm2 restart all`

P.S В логах видно, что крон стартует файл, но сама команда (в файле) не выполняется.

Comment: Может всё-таки надо `/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/pm2 restart all`?

Comment: Покажите вывод `which pm2`. И попробуйте полный путь написать потом в скрипте.

Comment: @Suvitruf /usr/bin/pm2

Comment: @ikerya cron что-нибудь пишет в лог ошибок?

Comment: Внутри скрипта вывод перенаправьте куда-нибудь типа `... > $(mktemp myfile-XXXXXX)`